# passing user input from main to inside a pool python

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing

I'm trying to pass some user input from main or outside main to the function running inside a multiprocessing pool. Code is something like below:

```
import multiprocessing

global var1
var1 = input("enter input: ")

def function1(arg1_A):
    x = var1 + 'string'
    do stuff

def MCprocess():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    pool.map(function1, listarg1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MCprocess()
```

Where do I put the input() function in order for all instances of function1 to receive it? Is there a better way of doing this?

To clarify. I've tried declaring var1 as global var1 within the function. That hasn't worked.

Comment: what does the `modules` module do and what is `arg1`?  also could you say what you mean by "that hasn't worked".  also is `multiprocessing` can be OS dependant, which OS do you care about.  see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @SamMason multiprocessing is a python module. you need an import statement to import it. I've updated the code to show that I'm importing that module. I am importing others. Thanks for pointing out arg1. I've updated that as well. in MCprocess, listarg1 is a list of files to be processed. in function1, arg1_A is an individual (any individual) belonging to that list.

Comment: apologies. missed the request for OS. Windows10.

Comment: I've not tested my answer under windows, but I expect it to work

Comment: I did. it works. accepted your answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

making this work portably (i.e. under Windows) is somewhat fiddly, but this should do the right thing:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def init(*args):
   global var1
   [var1] = args

def process(path):
    print(repr(var1), 'processing', path)

def MCprocess():
    var1 = input("enter input: ")
    with Pool(initializer=init, initargs=[var1]) as pool:
        pool.map(process, ['first', 'second'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MCprocess()
```

note that if you just care about Linux or OSX (i.e. where it [`fork`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.set_start_method) processes) you could get away with:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def process(path):
    print(repr(var1), 'processing', path)

var1 = input("enter input: ")
with Pool() as pool:
    pool.map(process, ['first', 'second'])
```